# Rails C command switches to inspect mode and doesn't work after that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I was following a tutorial and he used `rails c` to open the console to edit the database and add new things I wanted to do the same but it switches to **inspect mode** and when I type `Book.last` for example, this is what happens:

`(0.6ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*) Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]] (Object doesn't support #inspect)`

and If I type `Book.first`, it tells me **'Maybe IRB Bug'** I've been searching for days and I still can't find the solution for it.

I am using Windows 10, Gitbash.

Comment: I know this is not the answer, but whenever I see people using Rails on Windows I have to give a suggestion. Rails is not meant for Windows and it is really buggy(maybe that's the actual issue). I would recommend using Rails on Windows with WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux). Take a look at it on the internet and it will be a much better experience.

Comment: @Hady what do you mean when you say "it switches to inspect mode"? `Rails c` should switch to an IRB (Interactive RuBy) console with your app preloaded.

Comment: @cordev I really don't know much about it, can you give me some more info please?

Comment: @LesNightingill `Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.4)
Switch to inspect mode.` this is what it brings back when I type `rails c` and it doesn't work after that.

Comment: the internet says that this is a problem that several ppl have seen with windows/gitbash/rails. One solution suggested is here: https://fool-dev.com/switch-to-inspect-mode-on-gitbash-in-windows/ but I'm not a windows user so I can't offer any insight. Good luck!

Comment: @LesNightingill still doesn't work unfortunately but I appreciate your time, thank you!

Comment: @HadyKouider Here is a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-on-microsoft-windows-10) which can get you started with installing the WSL. It is basically a Ubuntu machine inside of your Windows. You can do everything Rails related within it and it will work nicely.